# Android drawCircle and drawOval flaw

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm trying to draw circle/oval on the `Canvas`. The view containing the canvas is scaled up to 20-times. Below is the picture which result I got at the moment. I'm aware of Android developers know the [issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23737) with `drawCircle` and `drawOval` methods. It is because both methods are using a hardware rendering.

[image]

The question is how to achieve the result like on the picture's leftmost. I tried to disable the hardware rendering for the specific view:

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Due to the view is scaled all I got is a pixelated picture (like 4.1.2 AA on).

Any ideas how to pass this Android's flaw in easy manner? The minimum SDK is set to 13, so I can't disable AA and make an assumptions that it will work on every device.  Using some math and drawing the circle point by point I can achieve good result, but it looks for the last-resort solution.

Comment: hi have you got any solution.If yes please share as I am facing the same .

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha there's no solution, it's a platform bug solved in later versions of Android OS.